# Retrieve Tab Header content

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, tabitem

Can anyone help me figure out a way to retreive the content of a tab header in WPF?

All I want is the text in the header so I can assign it to some other variable, but there doesn't seem to be any way of getting at it.

I am very new to WPF.. but the last hour or so googling this problem has not returned anything helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know how [casting and such](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) works, right?

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Name="_tabItem1" Header="MyHeader"/>
</TabControl>
```

```cs
//Header is an object and hence needs to be casted for retrieval as string
string headerText = (string)_tabItem1.Header;
MessageBox.Show(headerText);
```

[`TabItem.Header`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.header.aspx) can be anything, even complex controls so if you did not set this to a string yourself you cannot retrieve it as string like this either.

Comment: I see. This helped. I just needed to cast the Header to a TextBlock object. Thanks!

Comment: @Luke: Glad that helped! (You could [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left)

Answer (score 3):

**XAML:**

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock>SomeText</TextBlock>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

**To access a Text:**

```
((System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock)(((System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl)(this.tabControl.Items[0])).Header)).Text
```

**To acces a Content Control:**

```
 (System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl)(this.tabControl.Items[0])).Header)
```

Comment: Like, who would set the header like this? (Well, probably some people do but it is not very likely)

Comment: Or you could put and name on TextBlock x:Name="tbTC1" then access it via tbTC1.text.  Sllev, I like your answer as it covers the tabcontrol and headers nicely.

Comment: H.B. I set headers that way often.  It allows for formatting (e.g. line break) and alignment you don't get with in line.

Comment: @BalamBalam: That is justified, but if all you were to do is restricted to the code posted above that would not make much sense. (Also: Don't forget the `@`-sign or people won't be notified)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this. I cast the Header to a TextBlock. It's difficult at first to see what exactly Header is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TabItem.Header` 
e.g. following code will set `header` of the first tab to "New header":

```
(tabControl1.Items[0] as TabItem).Header="New header";
```